# The difference between has and had

Tags: tense

What's the difference between the two sentences?

> The singer has a nice voice.
>   The singer had a nice voice.

Answer (score 3):

**Has** is present tense (now), while **had** is past tense (in the past).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> 'Has' is the third person singular present tense of 'have' while 'had' is the third person singular past tense and past participle of 'have. ' 2. Both are transitive verbs, but 'has' is used in sentences that talk about the present while 'had' is used in sentences that talk about the past.

For more info look [here](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/has-vs-had/).

Some other examples:

- http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-has-and-had/
- https://writingexplained.org/has-vs-have-difference
- https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-%E2%80%9Chas%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9Chad%E2%80%9D-and-how-do-you-know-which-one-to-use
- https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/using-have-and-has/

Comment: Thanks, Can you give me another example

Comment: @Sdg I added some more examples :)